# Use alias in nested select subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query:

```
SELECT t.*,
    (SELECT SUM(subs)
    FROM (SELECT …
    FROM (SELECT prod_id, COUNT(*) subs
        FROM subscriptions s
        WHERE s.begin_date < t.week_of + interval 7 day AND
              s.end_date >= t.week_of
       GROUP BY 1) A
    LEFT JOIN …
    LEFT JOIN …
    WHERE …
    GROUP BY 1, 2) B) as num_subs
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(week, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, '2015-01-01', 
Ticket.timestamp), '2015-01-01') as week_of, COUNT(*) as Count_Tickets
      FROM . . .  -- rest of query here
     ) t ;
```

I'm trying to use the `t.week_of` column created in the from section to do the `s.begin_date` and `s.end_date` operations but I keep getting an `Unknown column 't.week_of' in 'where clause'` error. What is wrong with my syntax? How can I use the t alias in the `WHERE s.begin_date < t.week_of...` line?

Comment: A subquery can only reference tables one level out, but your subquery is nested several levels deep.

Comment: You'll need to use a join instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: @Student1 . . . The logic doesn't make sense.  A `group by` in a scalar subquery basically never makes sense.  You can just use the sub-subquery as a subquery to get the number of active subs (which was your original question).